# How to scroll an Imageview when gridview scroll

Tags: android, gridview, android-scrollview

[image]

I have one imageview & one gridview in my layout.

**What I am need,**

If I scroll the gridview up, I want to scroll this imageview also?
How can I achieve this..

I don`t need full answer..I want some direction & guidelines only.

Comment: I think this is what you want https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java

Comment: thanks @tyczj..I check it now..

Comment: You want to hide the image as the grid view scrolls, correct? 
You could use the onScrollListener of the GridView and change the position of the image (move it towards the top edge) and expand the height of the grid view at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the image as the grid view scrolls, correct? You could use the onScrollListener of the GridView and change the position of the image (move it towards the top edge) and expand the height of the grid view at the same time.